# Get the authenticated user attributes from the idp using the idp first login

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

### Background

1. I have multiple idps running in different folders on a server for
   different tenants
2. Each instance of the idp is accessed by users bound
   to a specific tenant
3. user sessions must be managed outside of saml so once they are authenticated through the idp they no longer have to login anywhere else system wide

Im currently initializing authentication using the idp first approach to a url like so

https://test1.domain.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?spentityid=urn:mace:feide.no:someservice&RelayState=https://admin-cis-gambier.domain.com

where test1 is the name of the tenant and the folder where simplesaml is installed.

Right now i am directed to the idp to login with the url . After authentication , i get sent back to the relaystate url correctly.

### Question

**How do i retrieve the currently authenticated user?** i know i have a session because when i goto the idp directly to test authentication it says im still logged in.

Comment: Where/when are you trying to retrieve the authenticated user?

Comment: After ive logged into the idp , looks like i was using an old version of simplesaml . Currently in the process of upgrading if it works ill close this

Comment: So you have a .php page on the idp that is protected and you want to get the user attributes? The [authenticate](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/master/modules/core/www/authenticate.php) used to test authentication shows how to do so. The php API used is [documented](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6)